# Record type selection screen is not shown prior to case creation

Tags: case, profile, record-type

we have multiple record type for cases. Before case creation a screen is shown where a user has to choose a record type (i guess its a Salesforce default screen).

The problem we are currently facing is that one user sees the screen while the other user does not. Both have the same profile assigned where all record types are configured as accessible.

Does anyone know why one sees the screen while the other doesn't?

Comment: Have you checked this section `User Name(in header) > My Settings > Display and layout > Set Default Record Types`.  Whether default Record Type is selected for that user.

Comment: @SarojBera thank you very much! That was exactly the problem!

Comment: Let me put this as an answer and please mark so. Maybe someone else will see this and find it useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check if any default Record Type is selected for that user by visiting **User Name(in header) > My Settings > Display and layout > Set Default Record Types**. If you have enabled the Record Type for a user profile and you still don't see it for some users, check that if you have selected default record type for that Object.